# How to download images in order in iOS Parse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery

I am trying to set up three `NSMutableArray` to use in `UITableView`.

Here is my code:

```
for (PFObject *object in objects) {

    PFUser *user = (PFUser *) object[@"user"];

    [ [user objectForKey:@"image"] getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error)
        {

            //Add Comment text
            [_commentsArray insertObject:[object objectForKey:@"comment"] atIndex:i];


            //Add comment Id
            [_commentIDArray insertObject:object.objectId atIndex:i];

            //Add user image
            [_picsArray insertObject:[UIImage imageWithData:data] atIndex:i ];

            if (i == [objects count]-1)
            {
                [self.tableView reloadData];

            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Errrror ==  %ld",(unsigned long)[_picsArray count]);
        }
        i++;
    }];
}
```

In the `PFQuery` I am ordering it:

```
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
```

But as far as I can understand image in first row is large. So it takes time to download it. So it goes to second loop. Try to download image. Size is small. Download finished. Add to array. Now download for first image is finished. Add to array but to second place. How can manage it so it add items one by one in the order?

Comment: So [user objectForKey:@"image"]  is returns Image URL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
// initially, add place holder
for (int i=0; i<objects.count; i++) {
    [_commentsArray addObject:@""];
    [_commentIDArray addObject:@""];
    [_picsArray addObject:@""];
}

for (PFObject *object in objects) {

    PFUser *user = (PFUser *) object[@"user"];

    [ [user objectForKey:@"image"] getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error)
        {

            NSInteger orderIndex = [objects indexOfObject:object];

            //Replace Comment text
            [_commentsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:[object objectForKey:@"comment"] atIndex:orderIndex];


            //Replace comment Id
            [_commentIDArray replaceObjectAtIndex:object.objectId atIndex:orderIndex];

            //Replace user image
            [_picsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:[UIImage imageWithData:data] atIndex:orderIndex ];


            if (i == [objects count]-1)
            {
                [self.tableView reloadData];

            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Errrror ==  %ld",(unsigned long)[_picsArray count]);
        }
        i++;
    }];
}
```

Comment: It works perfect when there is one user. But when I have two PFUser, it is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than downloading image and create array to populate tableview, you have to just create array of PFObjects and use it with [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for Asynchronous image downloading without any issue or blocking UI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the question is really about not expending effort to download images beyond the scroll position while the visible rows are still being fetched.

The solution to that problem is to load images lazily, when they're needed to configure a cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  There's plenty of generic content available about this idea.  For a parse-specific solution, [see PFImageView here](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/loading-remote-images-stored-on-parse/).

The gist is that image view will take care of loading and caching an image from the file.  It will do this asynchronously, so there will be a low perceived lag.  Just give the file to the image view and let it do the rest...

Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will look something like this:

```
// just guessing that your "objects" array is the table's datasource
PFObject *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
PFUser *user = (PFUser *) object[@"user"];

// put a PFImageView in the cell (in this case with a tag==32)
PFImageView *imageView = (PFImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:32];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@”placeholder.png”];
imageView.file = [user objectForKey:@"image"];  // assuming this is a file attribute
[imageView loadInBackground];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem that you try to do order based adding, where your blocks fire asynchronously so it can be in random order.

You should change to a dictionary or any other keyed data structure and use keys for your comments and pics (e.g. use comment id as the key).

Also double check if the callback of the block is executed on the main queue or any serial queue, because if it's not you need to add locks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my images were downloaded but not appearing in the order it should, my table view images and the titles were not matching.

To solve that, I created a column at my class in Parse.com that hold exclusively nameForImages, then each downloaded image is saved using this name.

The nameForImages had to be the same used for the column title, for example:

- Title = Pepperoni and Four Cheese | nameForImage =
  PepperoniAndFourCheese
- Title - Muzzarella and Spinach | nameForImage = MuzzarellaAndSpinach
- Etc...

This trick fit to solve my problem because the name of the image and the title appearing in the cell were short and had no special caracters.

I hope it helps or light a solution, good luck.